# Accessing key / value from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty

Tags: c#

Hi I have some json which is kinda awkward due to its nested/dynamic nature.

It looks something like below. Apologies if it's slightly off. I am trying to create a dictionary like `Dictionary <string, Dictionary<string,long>>`, where each date value is the first key and the item1 is the second key etc.

```
xyz {
    xyzcharacteristic1{
        "2022/10/01": {
            "item1": 0000,
            "item4": 11111,
            "item2": 33333,
            "item3": 33333,
        }
        "2022-09-05": {
            "item2": 0000,
            "item1": 11111,
            "item3": 22222,
            "item4": 22222,

        }...
    }, xyzcharacteristic2{...}, xyzcharacteristic3{...}
    xyy {
        xyycharacteristic1{...}...
    }
```

I have tried to parse it using a few methods ive seen on stack overflow but I just cant get access the key / values individually.

```
string json = r.ReadToEnd(); 
var rss = JObject.Parse(json);
var dates= ((JObject)rss["xyz"]["xyzcharacteristic1"]).Properties();

}
foreach (var item in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item); 
}
```

Comment: Try `foreach (var inner in ((JObject)item.Value)) { Console.WriteLine(inner); }` instead of `Console.WriteLine(item);`

Comment: thanks was driving me crazy that I couldnt access key/value

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko - [Can you do a proper answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment)

Comment: @vernou It's too small of an answer, but I suppose it may be helpful to people who search for it on the internet, so I guess I should add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue "unpacking" the values as you go through them in the loop, like this:

```
foreach (var inner in ((JObject)item.Value)) {
    Console.WriteLine(inner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to write all inner properties you need a double foreach loop

```
    var rss = JObject.Parse(json);
    var dates = ((JObject)rss["xyz"]["xyzcharacteristic1"]).Properties();
    foreach (var item in dates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"---- {item.Name} ----");
        foreach (var prop in ((JObject)item.Value).Properties())
            Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} : {prop.Value}");
    }
```

output

```
---- 2022/10/01 ----
item1 : 0
item4 : 11111
item2 : 33333
item3 : 33333
---- 2022-09-05 ----
item2 : 0
item1 : 11111
item3 : 22222
item4 : 22222
```